# Different behavior of ByteBuffer for Run and Debug

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-optimization, bytebuffer

```
byte[] arr;

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
buffer.put((byte) 0x00);
buffer.put(new byte[] {0x01, 0x02});
buffer.put(new byte[] {0x03, 0x04, 0x05});
buffer.put(new byte[] {0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09});
arr = buffer.array();

for(byte c : arr) {
    System.out.format("%d ", c);
}
```

When I run the above lines of code, it prints the output as I want.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

When I run it with Debug, I get the result I want again.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Now I put a breakpoint on any line. When I move the application with my hand with debug mode, only the last byte sequence is added. It actually adds all the byte arrays, but adds all of them starting from index 0 and result is

```
6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I don't know why acts like that. Is it a debugger problem?

I'm using IntelljIdea and java1.8.0_162. When i put VM options -Djava.compiler=NONE, everything works fine. What did this process change?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you clicked in your debugger in a way that made it skip the execution of the first three buffer.put lines.

Comment: It is not possible. I tried to put the break point to first line of code. I executed all commands one by one.